# Pass value of a StaticResource to ConverterParameter in a combine string

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter, staticresource

I wrote a converter that get

- `Value` as `Bool`
- `Parameter` as `String`

I use it like this:

```
BorderBrush="{Binding IsSelected,
                      Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorBrushConverter},
                      ConverterParameter='#ff00bfff;#0000bfff'}"
```

If `Value` is `True` then the converter return a `ColorBrush` from first color Hex code in Parameter else return a `ColorBrush` from second color hex code.

My converter work very well **But** I want know how can i use it like this:

```
<Color x:Key="MyColor1">#66bb66</Color>

--------------------

BorderBrush="{Binding IsSelected,
                      Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorBrushConverter},
                      ConverterParameter=#ff00bfff;{StaticResource MyColor1}}"
```

**Result in Design mode:**

[image]

**Result at RunTime:**

[image]

But i need color Hex code of the `StaticResource` in my parameter like this:

```
Parameter: "#ff00bfff;#66bb66"
```

My question is how can i pass a `StaticResource` value in a combine string to my `ConverterParameter`???

What is your solution?

Comment: Make the whole parameter string a resource *or* add a property to your converter and create multiple converter objects with different property values *or* use a MultiBinding with a IMultiValueConverter.

Comment: You cannot do that. Instead, add a property with the color that you can use to bind and from which you can call the converter.

Comment: This looks like the perfect task for a `MultiValueConverter`.

Comment: Thanks all, @Clemens, may you give me **3** very simple sample code (include **Signature of converter methods** and just **require lines of codes in XAML** to describe how to use it) for each one of **your 3 solution** in an answer?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a bit late, but hopefully this can help the late visitors:

here is the converter code:

```
public class BoolToBorderBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public SolidColorBrush TrueColor { get; set; }

    public SolidColorBrush FalseColor { get; set; }

    // this example compares a binding property (string) with 1 parameter (also in string)
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && parameter != null)
        {
            if (String.Compare(value.ToString(), parameter.ToString(), true) == 0)
            {
                return this.TrueColor;
            }
            else
            {
                return this.FalseColor;
            }
        }
        return this.FalseColor;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

then you can configure the converter in xaml like this (in the ResourceDictionary section):

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <local:BoolToBorderBrushConverter x:Key="BrushConverter" TrueColor="{StaticResource MyTrueColor}" FalseColor="Transparent">
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and this is how you use the converter:

```
<Border BorderBrush="{Binding MyProperty, Converter={StaticResource BrushConverter}, ConverterParameter=ABC}"/>
```